# How to read path variables / binding data in Python Azure BlobTrigger Function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

How do I read {email} in Python Azure BlobTrigger function?

function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "folder1/{email}/{filename}",
      "connection": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

**init**.py

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

def main(myBlob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Email: {??????}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my my environment and got expected results a below:

The code I have used by modifying your code is :

***init*.py**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes\n"
                 f"{myblob.name.split('/')[1]}")
```

[image]

**Function Json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "sample/{email}/{name}",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Follow the above process to get the required output.

Comment: in your code you are using "name" not "email"
you do not need to even put {email} in your function.json/path to work

I need to access email as a variable. It works in C#
 [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("resumes/{email}/{filename}", Connection = "RESUMES_CONTAINER_CONNECTION_STRING")] string myBlob, string email, string filename)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {email} \n Data: {myBlob}");
        }

Comment: AFAIK, in python you need to use that variable as ```myblob.name.split('/')[1]```. I would be happier and amazed if you can use like the way you do in C#.Will be Waiting for an answer, something like your comment.